# split window location accordingly

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

I am trying to redirect the user according to a lang choice drop down and using their current window.location

So if the user is visiting

1. `xxxx.com will need to go to xxxx.com/langchoice.`
   2.`xxxx.com/currentlang/test.php will need to go to xxxx.com/langchoice/test.php` 
   3 `xxxx.com/test.php will need to go to xxxx.com/langchoice/test.php`

I have done 1 and 2 but not particularly happy with the way that I coded this considering that if more languages might come I need to add a line every time...can this be rewritten better?

```
var s = window.location.href;

                if (s.indexOf(".php") !=-1) 
                {

                    if (s.indexOf("/en/") !=-1)
                    {
                    var location=window.location.href.replace("/en/","/"+evt.selectedItem+"/");
                    }
                    else if (s.indexOf("/gr/") !=-1)
                    {
                    var location=window.location.href.replace("/gr/","/"+evt.selectedItem+"/");
                    }
                    else if (s.indexOf("/it/") !=-1)
                    {
                    var location=window.location.href.replace("/it/","/"+evt.selectedItem+"/");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                      window.location.replace(location); 
                }
                else
                {
                    var location=window.location.href.replace("#","");
                    window.location.replace(location+evt.selectedItem); 
                }
```

Comment: You might want to experiment with RegEx.

Comment: Maybe dynamically create the language choice in backend (php), with the complete urls for each language version automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does make the check to see if there is a "language", but the basic idea to replace would be

There are many ways of doing it, this is one way

```
var orgPathName = window.location.pathname;
var newPathName = orgPathName.replace(/^\/[^\/]*/,"/" + evt.selectedItem);
var newUrl = window.location.href.replace(orgPathName, newPathName);
```

Now to do the detection, you do a simple test

```
var hasLang = (/^\/(en|gr|in)\//i).test(window.location.pathname);
```

pain with this is maintaining the language list

Answer (score 0):

How do you persist `langchoice`? Do you store it in a cookie?

I think you are essentially saying that the user should be at:

```
xxxx.com/[langchoice]etc
```

at all times.

So you could split on '/' and then, if it exists, check item [1]. If it matches the `langchoice` cookie, continue, if it doesn't, swap it out.